# Android Studio is drunk?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Recently Android Studio went completely insane by doing completely illogical stuff.
Look at the prints in the console:

`I/System.out: 0 + 518 < 518 is true`

`I/System.out: 518 + 518 < 518 is true`

then look at the code:

```
System.out.print(j + " + " + squareSize + " < " + squareWidth);

if (j + squareSize < screenSizeY) {
    squareHeight = squareSize;
    System.out.print(" is true");
} else {
    squareHeight = screenSizeY - j;
    System.out.print(" is false");
}
```

There are no other Threads that might change these variables. Did I oversee something obvious or did Android Studio just drink too much last night?

Comment: which AS version are you using ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android Studio. Are you dealing with float or double, and rounding errors? Is `screenSizeY == squareWidth`? If not, then *your* mistake should be obvious.

Comment: I see. AS chose to have some fun. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at these two lines:

```
(j + " + " + squareSize + " < " + squareWidth)
```

and

```
if (j + squareSize < screenSizeY)
```

if `squareWidth` is equal with `screenSizeY` then AS is drunk, else it is not :)

Comment: They are not equal. I must have overseen it several times because both names look very similar. I apologize to Android Studio for having made false assumptions about its drug consumption.

Answer (score 3):

Here you print `squareWidth`

```
System.out.print(j + " + " + squareSize + " < " + squareWidth);
```

And here already `screenSizeY` is checked:

```
if (j + squareSize < screenSizeY) {
```

Today is Friday, better let's drink a beer ourselves ;)